# Rust Option::map(...) call without argument or explicit function call inside closure

Tags: rust

*(Apologies for the confusing question title but I am still relatively new to Rust and wasn't sure how to phrase it better).*

I would generally call `Option::map(...)` like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x: Option<&str> = Some("Hello");
    let y: Option<String> = x.map(|s| s.to_string()); // <--
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", x, y);
}
```

I recently came across an example where `Option::map(...)` used as follows:

```
   let y: Option<String> = x.map(str::to_string);
```

Why does this work? What is this called in Rust-specific terminology.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It does...partially. I would still like to know how/why this works and if there is a specific name or term which is used to define this (mostly because I couldn't even figure out what to search for).

Comment: After going through the linked question, I Googled for "Rust function as closure" and saw this page in the results:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html

This page clearly describes this pattern.

Comment: FWIW the ability to use *methods* as *functions* (rather than functions as closures) is called [Uniform Function Call Syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0132-ufcs.md). Though Rust's version thereof is somewhat limited compared to [D's](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/gems/uniform-function-call-syntax-ufcs) where any free function can be used as a method. No closure is actually involved in your first snippet as [the anonymous function doesn't close over anything](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc698e5f6590b5e0774d03b9274d14aa).